# Visual Studio 2012 "Invalid license data. Reinstall is required"

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2012

I have a newly built Windows 8 VM with VS 2012 Premium running on it, when I try open any sln file I get the following modal pop up error

> Visual Studio 2010 Shell
>
> Invalid license data. Reinstall is required.

I can open the sln's if I open up VS and then do project open, this is really annoying, any ideas how I fix it?

*Note I have done a VS repair and it didn't solve it...and I never had any VS RC release on the machine, all new build with s/w downloaded from the MSDN

Cheers

Comment: Have you considered calling Microsoft?

Comment: Click the Workarounds tab: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/520110/invalid-license-data-reinstall-is-required

Comment: Thanks Hans, I will give it a try later, not sure why I'm getting this with VS 2012, the workaround is for Visual studio 2010...

Comment: I uninstalled VS 2012, I wasn't happy with this error on my machine and didn't trust this in the long run as a Dev Box. Thanks for the input

Comment: At £8000 a licence, you really would think that Microsoft could get this right.

Answer (score 11):

I encountered the same exact error when I created a solution with a full version of Visual Studio 2012 ***Professional*** on one machine and then tried to open the solution file with a copy of Visual Studio 2012 ***Express*** on a different machine. I got the error when double-clicking the solution file, but not when loading the solution into an already opened instance.

I ***fixed*** the error by opening the solution file (.sln) with notepad and changing the line that says `Visual Studio 2012` to say `Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows Desktop`.

After that, I was able to double-click to open the solution file on the machine that has Express installed.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using VS 2013. I fixed this by right clicking the .sln and setting the Open With parameter to visual studio 2013 and not VS version selector or VS 2010.

Answer (score 1):

I have faced the same problem. When I set the system Date and Time to the current Date and Time, The Problem solved by itself.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the `.sln` extension is owned by "Visual Studio 2010 Shell" a minimal version of Visual Studio that ships with products like SQL Server and Office to provide support for add-in development without any other features. Since this is a minimal version, it's unable to load any project type that ships with Visual Studio Express, Professional or above.

The same may happen when you have Visual Studio Express installed next to a full version of Visual Studio.

This may happen when you install an older version of Office or SQL Server after having installed Visual Studio. The old installer will hijack the extension.

To repair this problem:

1. use the "Open With" option of Windows and select the "Visual Studio Version Selector" as your default action.
2. Or open the "Default Programs" option in Windows, look up the .sln extension and make sure it uses the "Visual Studio Version Selector" as default: [image]
3. Or locate Visual Studio 2012 in the Programs and Features window of Windows and chose "Change", the Visual Studio installer will pop up, chose "Repair" to have it repair the file associations and any other problems that may arise by installing Visual Studio versions in reverse order (it may for example mess up the MsBuild directory as well).

Remember that when Visual Studio 2010 was released, it could not yet know what Visual Studio 2012 would change, as such, it's best to install versions of Visual Studio in the order they were released. This may sometimes prove difficult, as other products may install Visual Studio versions without you knowing.

Comment: This worked for me. Initially I did attempt to use the 'Open With' option and clicked on VS, but it still happened. After reading this I tried it again and noticed it said "**Keep** using Visual Studio **2010**", but I have 2012 installed, and didn't notice the option for "Visual Studio Version Selector", clicked on that one and no more problem.